# How to create a time delay with animation in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, animation, imageview

1. First we generate a random number (for example from say 0 to 10):

   ```
   If randomNumber = 0
       Animate imageSet0 [here we create an ImageArray and an animate function – please see code below)
   Else if randomNumber = 1
       Animate imageSet1
   Else if randomNumber = 2
       Animate imageSet2
   And so on…
   ```
2. Then we place a `DispatchQueue` timer that waits for the above animation to complete (time delay is equal to `animationDuration`), then we repeat the first step above and generate another random number and play another animation set:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + imageView.animationDuration) {
      [Insert code that repeats the first step above and generates another random number to play another animation set]
   }
   ```
3. In theory this random animation could play indefinitely until the user moves past this scene.

Here is my code thus far:

```
func createImageArray(total: Int, imagePrefix: String) -> [UIImage]{
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
    for imageCount in 0..<total {
        let imageName = "\(imagePrefix)-\(imageCount).png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)!

        imageArray.append(image)
    }

    return imageArray

}


func animate(imageView: UIImageView, images: [UIImage]){
    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + imageView.animationDuration) {

[Create code that repeats the first step above and generates another random number to play another animation set]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIView.animate(withDuration: delay: options: animations:)` api for that. Note delay parameter will let you start animation after certain delay.

Comment: Hi @Sandeep - how would you work in the random function to play one of the ten animations with the UIView.animate api?